# Several images with title

Tags: html, css

I have a background with an image, in this bakground I have 3 images with 3 numbers. I would like for each number, center the number with the image.
I am stuck with the property `margin-left`

```css
.background-picture-red{
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/jVWdfG4/bg-2.jpg);
}

.picture01{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(224,0,0,0.30);
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.picture01-title{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.picture02{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(224,0,0,0.30);
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.picture02-title{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.picture03{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(224,0,0,0.30);
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.picture03-title{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-picture-red"> 
   <img class="picture01" src="https://i.ibb.co/n3fv0YY/bitcoin34.png">
   <span class="picture01-title">138</span>
   <img class="picture02" src="https://i.ibb.co/qRSr1Wr/bitcoin46.png">
   <span class="picture02-title">258</span>
   <img class="picture03" src="https://i.ibb.co/BwT7gHz/bitcoin68.png">
   <span class="picture03-title">303</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example where I added to each title:

```
  margin-left: -43px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
```

- `margin-left: -43px` : because your image size is `86px` so `-43px` will be placed in the middle of the image
- `translateX(-50%)` : so the text will be centered depending of its own size

```css
.background-picture-red{
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/jVWdfG4/bg-2.jpg);
}

.picture01{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(224,0,0,0.30);
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.picture01-title{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: -43px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: 100px;
  
  position: absolute;
}

.picture02{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(224,0,0,0.30);
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.picture02-title{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: -43px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.picture03{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(224,0,0,0.30);
  float:left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.picture03-title{
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  margin-left: -43px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-picture-red"> 
   <img class="picture01" src="https://i.ibb.co/n3fv0YY/bitcoin34.png">
   <span class="picture01-title">138</span>
   <img class="picture02" src="https://i.ibb.co/qRSr1Wr/bitcoin46.png">
   <span class="picture02-title">258</span>
   <img class="picture03" src="https://i.ibb.co/BwT7gHz/bitcoin68.png">
   <span class="picture03-title">303</span>
</div>
```

---

But maybe you should use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to do that kind of thing.

Comment: Hello Maarti, thank you a lot, it's ok mercy. I was stuck since 2 hours